# What is the standpoint of the Syrian government on emigrants from Syria to other countries?

Tags: safety

This is a question I partially direct at Syrians or former Syrians about how their state or former state sees emigration, particularly but not only political emigration and economic emigration.

Comment: Interesting question, but might be better on the politics site?

Comment: You are pretty damn right @user16259